# remove swapped duplicates from a 2D array

Tags: python, numpy

If I have a numpy array as

```
[[0 1] 
[0 5] 
[1 0] 
[1 2]
[2 1] 
[2 3] 
[2 4]
[2 5]
[3 2]
[3 4]
[4 2]
[4 3]
[5 0]
[5 2]]
```

since [0,1] and [1,0] both exist, I want to remove any one of them.

so basically, if [x,y] = [y,x] in the array, remove any one of either [x,y] or [y,x]

final output should be

```
[[0 1] 
[0 5]
[1 2]
[2 3]
[2 4]
[2 5]
[3 4]]
```

the removed elements should be

```
[[1 0]
[2 1]
[3 2]
[4 2]
[4 3]
[5 0]
[5 2]]
```

Comment: I'n sorry if i didn't frame the question well, hope you get the idea of what I mean

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sort along axis `0`, then use `unique` with `return_index` to dedupe.

```
u = np.sort(arr, axis=1)

_, idx = np.unique(u, axis=0, return_index=True)

arr[idx]
```

```
array([[0, 1],
       [0, 5],
       [1, 2],
       [2, 3],
       [2, 4],
       [2, 5],
       [3, 4]])
```

Comment: You don't really need to return the index in `np.unique` (that is optional). The following also works: `np.unique(np.sort(arr, axis=1), axis=0)`. For whatever it is worth.

Comment: @MarkBakker that doesn’t guarantee that I get the first duplicate. If the flipped version comes first I will get that instead.

Comment: I thought the question asked for 'remove any one of either [x,y] or [y,x], which I interpreted to mean it doesn't matter which one is removed. but if that matters, returning the index and using that is better.